# Parsing JSON data containing new line chars in a iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4.3

I have a problem parsing JSON data containing new line chars (`\n` etc) in iOS application. I use XCode 4.3. I have added the code I used to parse JSON; the application crashes when it finds a new line char.  How to replace or handle the newline char in JSON data parser or replace it in `NSString`?

```
NSString *jsonData = @"[{ "department": "","email_address1":"user@company.com"}]";    
jsonData = [jsonData stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSError *e = nil;
NSData *projNSdata = [jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: projNSdata options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this `modified` `jsonData` `string` it working perfectly. As `problem` is with `json` `string` :

```
NSString *jsonData = @"[{\n \"department\": \"\",\"email_address1\":\"user@company.com\"}]";
```

`Replace mine with yours`.

`Error` is at double quote with no value :

```
NSString *jsonData = @"[{ "department": "","email_address1":"user@company.com"}]";  
                                       here
```

Also add below line at the end:

```
NSLog(@"Json : %@  \n Error :%@",jsonArray,[e description]);
```